# how to install latest version of Rmarkdown? `install.packages()` is stuck at v1.10

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm reading the [PowerPoint Presentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/powerpoint-presentation.html) chapter of Rmarkdown. It states an Rmarkdown requirement `rmarkdown >= v1.9`. I do a `packageVersion('rmarkdown')` and learn I'm way behind, I have version `1.10`!

I proceed to `install.packages("rmarkdown")` and it installs `1.10`?!? How do I get the newer `1.9` version?

Comment: `1.10` is newer than `1.9` Basically the number after the decimal version numbers should be treated as separate numbers, not decimal places. And `1.10` is the latest version on CRAN. `compareVersion("1.10", "1.9")`

Comment: Here's my attempt at a joke `1.10 > 1.9
[1] FALSE`. And thanks for pointing out the obvious which I didn't realize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version numbers are different from decimal numbers:

```
> package_version("1.9") > package_version("1.10")
[1] FALSE
```

Each part is interpreted as separate integer. Otherwise version numbers like `1.2.5` wouldn't make much sense, but they are very common especially with [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).

Comment: Life would have been so much easier if people used x-y-z for semver instead of x.y.z